# How to find PBC pair?

Tags: c++, cryptography, pbcopy

I am using PBC library for cryptographic operations writing in C++ and I am stack in finding how to put two element like

> C = (g^r , H(X))

.

For pairing operation, for eg:

> e(g^r , H(X))

can be used with `element_pairing(pp, g^r, H(X))`

But for normal two elements putting like this together `C = (g^r , H(X))`, what function can I use from PBC?